# What is the best way to sum information from two separate tables in SQL with join?

Tags: sql, join, sum

I have two tables with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE COST1 (
    ID,
    COUNTER,
    COST
)

CREATE TABLE COST2 (
    ID,
    COUNTER,
    COST
)
```

`ID` can be used for a `JOIN`; and while `COUNTER` and `COST` are have the same name in both tables they are not related to each other the way `ID` is. I would like to create a result set `COST3` that has the form:

```
ID, sum(COST1.cost) + sum(COST2.cost).
```

Here is what I have come up with but I don't know if summing over the original tables with a `GROUP BY` that results from the `JOIN` would work as I intend?

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    ( sum(c1.COST) + sum(c2.COST) ) as COST_TOTAL
FROM
    COST1 c1
    JOIN COST2 c2 ON c1.ID = c2.ID
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

With some data, here is what the result should look like:

COST1

| ID | Counter | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 50 |
| A | 2 | 30 |
| B | 1 | 25 |
| B | 2 | 30 |

COST2:

| ID | Counter | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 20 |
| A | 2 | 40 |
| B | 1 | 50 |
| B | 2 | 10 |
| B | 3 | 20 |

COST3:

| ID | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A, | 140 |
| B, | 135 |

Comment: @Dai how else do I combine 50 & 30 from `COST1` for ID `A`?

Comment: Oh, I just saw that `ID` is **not** actually unique... why do you have a non-unique column named `ID`? That's a bad database design: column names should indicate their purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 create table COST1(ID varchar(5), Counter int,Cost int);
 insert into COST1 values('A', 1, 50  );
 insert into COST1 values('A', 2, 30  );
 insert into COST1 values('B', 1, 25  );
 insert into COST1 values('B', 2, 30  );
 insert into COST1 values('C', 2, 30  );
  
 
 create table COST2(ID varchar(5), Counter int,Cost int);   
 insert into COST2 values('A', 1, 20  );
 insert into COST2 values('A', 2, 40  );
 insert into COST2 values('B', 1, 50  );
 insert into COST2 values('B', 2, 10  );
 insert into COST2 values('B', 3, 20  );
 insert into COST2 values('D', 3, 20  );
```

Query#1 (To get sum for all the IDs which are available in both tables)

```
 Select C1.ID, (C1.cost+C2.cost) as Cost
 from
     (select ID, sum(COST) cost from COST1
 group by ID) C1
 
 Inner join
     (select ID, sum(COST) cost from COST2
 group by ID) C2
 
 on C1.ID=C2.ID
 GO
```

Output:

| ID | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A | 140 |
| B | 135 |

Query#2 (To get sum for all the IDs which are available in any of the tables)

```
 select ID, sum(cost) Cost
 from (
     (select id, cost
        from cost1
     ) union all
     (select id, cost
      from cost2
     )
     ) Cost3
 group by id;
 GO
```

Output:

| ID | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A | 140 |
| B | 135 |
| C | 30 |
| D | 20 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83fd82ce95927deee9cd77ea71505885)*

Answer (score 0):

Consider performing the aggregation of non-unique `ID` rows in inner-queries:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( c1.group_id, c2.group_id ) AS id,
    ( COALESCE( c1.group_cost, 0 ) + COALESCE( c2.group_cost, 0 ) ) AS total_cost
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            cost1.id AS group_id,
            SUM( cost1.cost ) AS group_cost
        FROM
            cost1
        GROUP BY
            cost1.id
    ) AS c1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            cost2.id AS group_id,
            SUM( cost2.cost ) AS group_cost
        FROM
            cost2
        GROUP BY
            cost2.id
    ) AS c2
        ON c1.group_id = c2.group_id
)
ORDER BY
    id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sum over a union of a sum:

```
select id, sum(s) COST_TOTAL
from (
  select id, sum(cost) s
  from cost1
  group by id
  union all
  select id, sum(cost)
  from cost2
  group by id
) u
group by id
```

Note that you need the “all” version of `union` to preserve duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use `union all` in a subquery and then aggregate:

```
select id, sum(cost)
from ((select id, cost
       from cost1
      ) union all
      (select id, cost
       from cost2
      )
     ) ic
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

union all the two table then group by id the subquery.  use a case when to partition between the two tables a specific column value.

```
 create table #COST1(ID varchar(5), Counter int,Cost int);
  insert into #COST1 values('A', 1, 50  );
  insert into #COST1 values('A', 2, 30  );
  insert into #COST1 values('B', 1, 25  );
  insert into #COST1 values('B', 2, 30  );
  insert into #COST1 values('C', 2, 30  );


  create table #COST2(ID varchar(5), Counter int,Cost int);   
  insert into #COST2 values('A', 1, 20  );
  insert into #COST2 values('A', 2, 40  );
  insert into #COST2 values('B', 1, 50  );
  insert into #COST2 values('B', 2, 10  );
  insert into #COST2 values('B', 3, 20  );
  insert into #COST2 values('D', 3, 20  );

   SELECT ID, 
   Sum(case when Type='Cost1' then Cost else 0 end+case when Type='Cost2' then Cost       else 0 end) Cost, 
   Sum(Counter) Counter
   FROM
   (
   SELECT *,'Cost1' Type FROM #COST1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *,'Cost2' Type FROM #COST2
   )x
   group by ID

   drop table #COST1
   drop table #COST2
```

output

```
ID  Cost    Counter
A   140     6
B   135     9
C   30      2
D   20      3
```